# Web scraping - scraping data for multiple URL's gives None

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

**1)** I am trying to scrape data for multiple URL's stored in CSV, but in result it gives None.

**2)** I want to store the fetched data simultaneously in rows one by one in a dataframe named `df` but it only stores one row.

here's my code(i have pasted below from where the data extraction started) -

```
import csv
df=pd.DataFrame()
with open('test1.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig' ) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        link = line[0]
        print(type(link))
        print(link)
        driver.get(link)
        height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        for scrol in range(100,height,100):
            driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0,{scrol})")
            time.sleep(0.2)
        src = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
        name_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'flex-1 mr5'})
        name_loc = name_div.find_all('ul')
        name = name_loc[0].find('li').get_text().strip()
        loc = name_loc[1].find('li').get_text().strip()    
        connection = name_loc[1].find_all('li')
        connection = connection[1].get_text().strip()
        exp_section = soup.find('section', {'id': 'experience-section'})
        exp_section = exp_section.find('ul')
        div_tag = exp_section.find('div')
        a_tag = div_tag.find('a')
        job_title = a_tag.find('h3').get_text().strip()
        company_name = a_tag.find_all('p')[1].get_text().strip()
        joining_date = a_tag.find_all('h4')[0].find_all('span')[1].get_text().strip()
        exp = a_tag.find_all('h4')[1].find_all('span')[1].get_text().strip()
        df['name']=[name]
        df['location']=[loc]
        df['connection']=[connection]
        df['company_name']=[company_name]
        df['job_title']=[job_title]
        df['joining_date']=[joining_date]
        df['tenure']=[exp]
df
```

output -

```
    name    location    connection  company_name    job_title   joining_date    tenure
0   None    None    None    None    None    None    None
```

I am not sure whether the for loop goes wrong or whats the exact problem but for a single URL it works fine.

I am using Beautiful soup for the first time so I  don't have proper knowledge. Please help me to make the desired changes. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? E.g. You have selenium code but no import or instantiation. Also, what urls are you using (couple of examples)? Please see [mcve] and [ask] for guidance on posting. In order to help you we need to be able to reproduce your problem on our own machines.

Comment: I am really sorry sir for not posting my complete code, I thought it would be difficult to read such a long code. Please don't delete the post for my silly mistake,

here's the csv and python file - https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2442ddfc887537169159d36ef6aa08b020210324054952/5f44be

Comment: No sir , actually I have my links stored in csv, but sir I have given we transfer link there you will get the csv as well as my complete code. Please go through it sir you don't have to face any problem in the code

Comment: @QHarr sir, will it be okay?

Comment: ok sir let me try to do it for two urls

Comment: Is your loop not just overwriting each time? Instead append to lists and create dataframe at end?

Comment: sir i have changed the code for two urls, may I edit my qstn and post that changed code?

Comment: @QHarr no sir i dont think it gets overwrite because in middle of the way i am printing those links between the loops and it shows different links is taken in each iteration

Comment: This `df['name']=[name]` doesn't append. It just keeps setting the same item to whatever the current value of name is within a single list

Comment: @QHarr yes sir I knew but to correct that what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the end of your code is appending new lines to the dataframe.

Try replacing df["name""] = [name] and the other lines with the following:

```py
new_line = {
    "name": [name],
    "location": [loc],
    "connection": [connection],
    "company_name": [company_name],
    "job_title": [job_title],
    "joining_date": [joining_date],
    "tenure": [exp],
}
temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_line)
df.append(temp_df)
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir for your reply,  I knew that it dosnt store the data correctly that exactly i am excepting from someone to correct the last part but sir it gives me an error - `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index` in the line `temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_line)`

Comment: sir its my request not to use sorry for me :)...you are my senior

Comment: Sir it worked, now it dosnt show any error, sir can you help me regarding the loop part for a csv?..thats the only thing which is left

Comment: I suppose you could encapsulate your code in a general loop to iterate over a list of csv file names: for csv_name in csv_list: ... with open(csv_name, newline ...).

Comment: yes sir i knew, but reputation less than 15 dosnt get displayed, have a nice day sir